# Transformation of probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'd like to compute the pdf of $w= g_1(x) = \frac{x}{1+e^{-x}}$ in dependence of the density $f_x(x)$ with domain $x>0$.

As I was not able to write the inverse function of $g_1(x)$, I tried the following approach:

I defined $u=g_1(x) = \frac{x}{1+e^{-x}}$ and $v=g_2(x)=e^{-x}$.
To compute the inverse function $g_1$, I then wrote $g_1$ as $u=g_1(x) = \frac{x}{1+v}$, giving this:

$x=g_1^{-1}(u,v)=u(1+v)$ and $x=g_2^{-1}(u,v)=-\ln(v)$.

I computed then the partial derivatives as:
$\frac{\partial g_1^{-1}}{\partial u} = 1+v$, $\frac{\partial g_1^{-1}}{\partial v} = u$, $\frac{\partial g_2^{-1}}{\partial u} = 0$, $\frac{\partial g_2^{-1}}{\partial v} = -1/v$.

resulting in the following joint-density of $u,v$:

$f_{u,v}(u,v)=\vert \frac{1+v}{v} \vert f_x(x = g_i^{-1}(u,v) ) $

This results seems rather strange to me because, when I use $g_2$ in $f_x(x)$, then there is no dependency on $u$. Therefore, my question is whether is approach is right and if not how to compute the the pdf of $w$.

Comment: Is $f_X(x)$ define over $(\infty,\infty)$? If so the transformation is not one-to-one. Also you need to define the space where $f_{u,v}(u,v)$ is non-zero. This will be a curve in $\mathbb{R}$, so there will be dependency on $u$ implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added that $f_x(x)$ is non-zero only for $x>0$. I already guessed that the mapping is non one-to-one (this was also the reason why I introduced the dummy variable $u$ - in the hope that this would fix the problem). Because $x>0$ only $v>0,u>0$ are allowed, right? But is the calculation in general correct? I'm especially unsure about the step where $v$ has been inserted into $g_1^{-1}$.

Comment: Your $u$ and $v$ are not _jointly_ continuous random variables and thus do not have a _joint_ density function. Thus your work is not applicable to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks for your comment. Can you help me with some sketch of how I can tackle this problem?